# How to join a dataset by row index?

Tags: r, left-join

I have one dataset that looks like this

| Rownumber | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | John |
| 7 | Ken |
| 9 | Marvin |

I have another that looks like this

| LastName |
| --- |
| Ming |
| Roe |
| Martin |
| Hugo |
| Sawyer |
| Wallace |
| Thomas |
| Wang |
| Abdul |

Note that I want to join second dataset to first. In the first I have a column called row number and the second I don't, but I have a backend index.

I would like my dataset to look like this

| Rownumber | Name | Last name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | John | Sawyer |
| 7 | Ken | Thomas |
| 9 | Marvin | Abdul |

You see that in the second dataset Sawyer is the 5th row, Thomas is the 7th, and Abdul is the 9th that is way it merged.

Comment: Are your datasets stored in data.frames?

Comment: Yes both datasets are in data frames.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose your data are stored in two data.frames named `df` and `df2`, you could use a `dplyr` `join`:

```r
library(dplyr)
df2 %>% 
  mutate(Rownumber = row_number()) %>% 
  right_join(df, by = "Rownumber") %>% 
  select(Rownumber, Name, LastName)
```

This returns

```r
  Rownumber   Name LastName
1         5   John   Sawyer
2         7    Ken   Thomas
3         9 Marvin    Abdul
```

- First create row numbers for your data.frame containing the last names.
- Next `right_join` the first data.frame by `Rownumber`.

### Data

```
df <- structure(list(Rownumber = c(5, 7, 9), Name = c("John", "Ken", 
"Marvin")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")

df2 <- structure(list(LastName = c("Ming", "Roe", "Martin", "Hugo", 
"Sawyer", "Wallace", "Thomas", "Wang", "Abdul")), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you can try this without `left_join`

```
> transform(df,LastName = df2$LastName[Rownumber])
  Rownumber   Name LastName
1         5   John   Sawyer
2         7    Ken   Thomas
3         9 Marvin    Abdul
```

Comment: I'm totally stunned that this even works. Great!

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use `merge`, where we use `Rownumber` from `df1` for `by.x`, then use `0` from `df2` for `by.y`, which refers to the row names.

```
merge(df1, df2, by.x = "Rownumber", by.y = 0, all.x = TRUE, all.y = FALSE)
```

**Output**

```
  Rownumber   Name LastName
1         5   John   Sawyer
2         7    Ken   Thomas
3         9 Marvin    Abdul
```

**Data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(Rownumber = c(5, 7, 9), Name = c("John", "Ken", 
"Marvin")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")

df2 <- structure(list(LastName = c("Ming", "Roe", "Martin", "Hugo", 
"Sawyer", "Wallace", "Thomas", "Wang", "Abdul")), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = "data.frame")
```